# Django forms. Fields with the same html name attribute

Tags: django, django-forms, forms

I am having a problem with django forms.
I am currently using the request.POST to validate the POST within views.
I want to decouple things a bit by moving the whole process to forms.

What do I want to do:
User is presented with 5 input texts. And he can add up to 30 texts total using javascript.
Each input text has name='choices[]' attribute. So when I get the request.POST dict, I simply do:

```
choices = request.POST.getlist('choices[]')
```

and I get all user's choices.

How can this be implemented with django forms?
For example the following form:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    # Form fields
    title = forms.CharField()
    choice1 = forms.CharField()
    choice2 = forms.CharField()
    option = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(...))
```

will produce something like this in HTML:

```
<input name="title" type="text" />   
<input name="choice1" type="text" />
<input name="choice2" type="text" />
<select name="option">
    <option .... />
       ....
</select>
```

is it possible to make it produce the following without manually hardcoding it into the HTML file myself?:

```
<input name="title" type="text" />   
<input name="choices[]" type="text" />
<input name="choices[]" type="text" />
<select name="option">
    <option .... />
       ....
</select>
```

and if yes how can I handle the validation afterwards?

Thank you

P.S I read the docs about django formsets, but this is about creating multiple forms, not 1 form, so I don't think it will be of any use.

Comment: Read the `formset` docs again. This is what you need. `Formset` is a set of `forms`, its not just one `form`.

Comment: Uhm ok I avoided to mention that the whole form consists of more elements, not only choices. If I provide an extra=3 it will provide 3 extra forms, whereas I only want 3 extra choice fields.  Am I missing something?
Also does this solve the name issue?

Comment: You can divide the problem into parts and solve them one by one (divide and conquer), check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular `form` for the rest of the `fields` and a `formset` for the `choices`.

```
#in your forms.py
from django import forms
class MyMainForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()

class MyChoicesForm(forms.Form):
    choice = forms.CharField()

MyChoicesFormset = forms.formset_factory(MyChoicesForm)

#in your views.py
def my_manage_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyMainForm(request.POST)
        formset = MyChoicesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            # do something with the form and formset.cleaned_data
            pass
    else:
        form = MyMainForm()
        formset = MyChoicesForm()
    return render(request, 'my_manage_view.html', {
        'form': form,
        'formset': formset
    })


#in your template you can render them inside one <form> tag
<form method="post" action="">
    {{ form }}
    <table>
        {{ formset }}
    </table>
</form>
```